# Variable + HTML to Button + Ruby on Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, button

I am having a an issue.

```
<%= link_to "<button>Add</button>".html_safe, new_admin_course_path, :id=>"open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class=>"inbox-sf-add-btn tip" %>
```

What if I want to add a ruby variable and some normal text the button? e.g. $25,- (where the $ and ,- are fixed and the 25 variable...I am quite new to this...sorry if this is too easy, but struggling. I tried a lot of options and googled for long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do like

amount = 25 #amount is the ruby variable

```
<%= link_to "<button>Add $#{amount}</button>".html_safe, new_admin_course_path, :id=>"open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class=>"inbox-sf-add-btn tip" %>
```

and I personally dont add `<button></button>` to the link and I rather use CSS to get the look and feel

Answer (score 1):

The correct helper you want for this is [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to).

To use a variable in the button text is defined as [string iterpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation). In your example it could be something like:

```
<%= button_to "$#{cost}", new_admin_course_path %>
```

Check out the **button_to** api reference for more options.

Answer (score 0):

Put your link inside a `<button></button>` tag. It'll be more readable.

And use variables interpolation in double-quoted strings to insert variable's value into string (the `#{@variable_name}` part)

```
<button>    
  <%= link_to "$#{variable_name}", new_admin_course_path, :id=>"open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class=>"inbox-sf-add-btn tip" %>
</button>
```