# Submit button with multiline value in rails & haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

For some cases, I'd like to have multiple lines in 'Submit' button value.
I'm using Rails 6 and haml.

This is what I've came up with (don't work):

**form_view.html.haml:**

```
- if @count < 0
  - check_btn_val = "Submit"
- else
  - check_btn_val = "Submit<br>You have " + @count + " submissions remaining"
%input{"type" => "submit", "value" => check_btn_val, ...}
```

<br> is ignored and treated as plain text (button label contains "<br>" indside the value).

I've seen this question [HTML: can I display button text in multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469088/html-can-i-display-button-text-in-multiple-lines) but I don't think this works for me, as it splits line based on fixed width of the button and my goal is to have break in specific place.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is more similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007980/variable-html-to-button-ruby-on-rails-views), so you could use string interpolation:

```
   - if @count < 0
      - check_btn_val = "Submit"
    - else
      - check_btn_val = "Submit<br>You have $#{@count} submissions remaining".html_safe
    %input{"type" => "submit", "value" => check_btn_val, ...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, html_safe did not help me. However, I've improved my stackoverflow (aka google) query and run into this question which accepted answer (use %button and put label (value) between tags) solved my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469088/html-can-i-display-button-text-in-multiple-lines

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it for my case:

```
- addtnl_txt = ""
- if @count >= 0
  addtnl_txt = "You have $#{@count} submissions remaining"
%button{"type" => "submit", "value" => check_btn_val, ...}
  Submit
  %br
  #{addtnl_txt}
```

Works nice, i.e. `%br` is ignored if `addtnl_txt` is empty